# What are these cartridges that many characters have in the Star Wars movies?

Tags: star-wars, props

Admiral Ozzel has them on both sides of his uniform (upper chest).  Most Imperial officers seem to have them.

Han, pictured also here, has three such cartridges on his jacket.  I'd like to make such a jacket and use anything that looks like them.  I figure they are most closely related to cartridges for guns.  (which is what I imagine they are in the films).

But does anyone know the real scoop on them?  What is their purpose in the Star Wars universe?

Admiral Ozzel:

[image: They seem to be on both sides of his chest]

And Han Solo:

[image: Han has three separate pockets on the upper left side of his chest]

Comment: Well, to be honest, i did google it "star wars what is in pockets". Just like that. :D And there is something else that i just found - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112958/what-are-those-things-in-hans-pocket

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Imperial forces

The [Star Wars Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Dictionary) identifies them as [Code Cylinders](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_code_cylinder). They're used to allow Imperial officers to identify themselves to the computer terminals and to carry memos, plans and orders.

[image]
[image]

### Han Solo

Interestingly, it would appear that the ones strapped to Han's front *aren't* code cylinders, but are in fact detonators for the explosives that he habitually carries.

I've put an image of the detonator (from the [Force Awakens Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_The_Visual_Dictionary)) alongside a close-up of the cylinders on Han's jacket.

[image]

Comment: I was really hoping they would turn out to be nitrous oxide canisters. Oh, well.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - Or Deathsticks :-)

Comment: If they are just for identification and notes, why do they need so many? I have microSD cards that store 64 gigabytes of data in a fraction of that size. I bet they're filling them up with porn.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - Well, you need at least one to identify yourself to the ship and one to send off with any coded orders. That means that you need at least two before you've even started.

Comment: I see you've bought into the Imperial propaganda. ;-)

Comment: @JohnSensebe - Silence, Rebel scum.

Comment: @user7812 - You don't want to carry Deathsticks.

Comment: @JohnSensebe "I have microSD cards that store 64 gigabytes of data in a fraction of that size."  How easy is it to misplace?